# Magento 2.1.8 - Display Attribute on Product Page

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes

I am new to Magento 2 and still in the learning process. Being a small business owner, Googling can only get me so far sometimes. I need to add a Hero Image at the top of the product page. If this was Magento 1, I would create an attribute as a text area and then add it to the view.phtml file. The text area is where the caption info would be and everything else would be done via CSS.

File `/theme/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Call the attribute

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('name');
    if ( is_object($attribute) ) {
        $identifier = $_product->getData("name");
    }
?>
```

Place this in the view.phtml where I want it to go on the product page itself.

```
<div class="hero"><?php echo $_product->getData('name'); ?></div>
```

This obviously does not work in Magento 2.1.8. How would I go about them same thing for Magento 2?

Thank you for any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It depends on your theme structure. But the main principle is to add attribute to product and then output image url to wanted template. Template of product page is in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog`.

Comment: I added the same code above into the view.phtml in Magento 2 structure, and I ended up getting a white screen which means it would be a PHP issue. I just assumed I did it wrong or Magento 2 is different and the code I used was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use catalog_product_view.xml to include custom phtml file. Like below code:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
            name="product.view.extra"
            template="Namespace_Module::custom.phtml" before="-">

    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

then in `custom.phtml` file you can get product attribute like below:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
<div class="hero"><?php echo $_product->getData('name'); ?></div>
```